# Type or namespace not found of user control project

Tags: c#, user-controls

The title suggest a easy problem.

But iam totally stuck at it.

I created a user control project to desgin my on control.
I build it and tested it. 
It all works fine up to this part.

When i tried to add this control to my project visual studio told me that the type or namespace could not be found.
I got this error a few times before so i checked my references. But that was all fine.

So i created a test project added the control to that project and everything works fine.

I really don't know what the problem is.

Then i created a new usercontrol project used different namespaces and class names. 
Because i thought that that would be the problem.

But the exact same thing happend. 
In my test project it works fine. No reference error. But when i added it to my "main" project i got a reference error.

So if anyone could please help me out...

Here some code:
this is the class of the user control

```
namespace WET.Components.extendedCombobox
{
    public partial class combobox: UserControl
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

this line is added in the designer class.
the reference is added. but it cannot find the WET  namespace

```
private WET.Components.extendedCombobox.combobox txtBedrijfsnaam;
```

Comment: Have you checked over the Output and Error windows when adding the reference to your main project? If it can't find the control it seems likely that the assembly didn't load as you expected - check framework versions in the build properties too.

Comment: @Dave The build project of my main project is framework 4 client profile and my usercontrol lib is .net framework 4.5. Iam gonna change  it and you will here back from me

Comment: user214623, I've added an answer if you don't mind flagging it as correct.

Comment: @user214623 Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the hollow check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check build framework versions and assemblies. then check in the Errors and Output windows when adding the reference and compiling to see if there are any conflicts.